# Reply to answerer

Tags: support, comments, questions

1. When I post a question, the answerers ask me questions or they need clarification about my question. Where should I answer their question? I can't comment, because I do not have 50 points. I added an answer, and it was deleted.
2. How do I add a picture to my question, answer or comments?

Comment: 1. You can comment if it is your question. 2. You can if you have enough rep. For now just post the url and higher rep users will edit it in.

Comment: Yes you can comment. Commenting on answers posted to your own questions does not require any reputation.

Comment: Did you actually try commenting in your own post?

Comment: If you add a picture of your error messages I'm going to reach through the internets and smack you.

Answer (score 17):

1. Clarifications are best edited into the original question, so that instead of an unclear question and a bunch of comments, the readers will find a clear question. But as others said, you can leave comments on your own post, too.
2. You can add a picture to a post by clicking a button in the editor that looks like a picture. On most sites, including Home Improvement, this requires no reputation. (On Stack Overflow it does.) There is no support for images in comments; only links to them can be posted in comments.

Answer (score 4):

Most is covered by the answer of *Yes* already.

Some other points:

1. You can comment if it is your question. You can use that to reply on an answer or comment on something not directly relevant to the question. If it is relevant for future readers, you should edit it in the question and probably comment to the one commenting you updated the question.
2. You can add images using the image icon in the editor. If you don't have enough reputation yet, you can't post images yet, or not that much. First determine if the images are really necessary. If not, leave them out. Else you can just post the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) and higher rep users will edit it in if deemed useful.